# C# to excel template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

i would like to make make an Excel where the template has to look like the image:

[ExcelTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACE0A.png)

my question is how is a good way to get the empty spaces, like those i need? any ideas?

Sorry my bad english
best regards Eric

Comment: Huh? How this Excel template is related to C# and ASP.NET? Can you clarify your question? Right now it is quite unclear what are you trying to achieve and what is your actual problem.

Comment: sorry, i would like to call my controller action, then create a Excel looking like my picture where "#" is data from Model. My issue is am having trouble Setting it up with a gridview. Was wondering if there was other solutions out there to create something that looks similar to my image(agian sorry for my english).

Comment: Well, in your case I would say you need some library for creating Excel files rather than any kind of gridview. For example, you can you NPOI. So in your controller you'll get data from DB, open existed excel template using NPOI, traverse cells and set those cells values accordingly. Then just return this excel file from action as `FileContentResult`.

Comment: hm sounds reasonable, i will check it out thanks.